# place figures side by side in two column format

Tags: floats, overleaf

I want to align graphs like this below figure in IEEE 2 column format

[image]

I tried this code but its placing figures up and down not side by side

```
\begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}%{c.PNG} % first figure itself
        \caption{first figure}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}%{h.PNG} % second figure itself
        \caption{second figure}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Why didn't you use the `figure*` environment?

Comment: Can you please edit this question and also show us your preamble so that we can just copy+paste a working MWE?

Answer (score 1):

I can't see the exact document class and packages you are using, but by using the `twocolumn` option in the document class `scrarctl` I managed it as follows

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[3]
\begin{figure*}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
        \captionof{figure}{first figure}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
        \captionof{figure}{second figure}
    \end{minipage}
    \par 
    \begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
        \captionof{figure}{third figure}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
        \captionof{figure}{fourth figure}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure*}
\blindtext[3]
\end{document}
```

Figure 1 and 2 are side by side, such is the case with figure 3 and 4. I just placed 4 minipages inside a figure and seperated them with a single `\par`. 
The generated PDF looks like this
[image: 4ducks]